# A question about the Java File class and its Serialization maybe？

Tags: java, list, file, serialization, gson

I don't know why the isFile() of the element f in the files list traversed by the for loop in the FileInit class in the code below is always false.false. But if delete the content related to FileItem, it will return to normal.It's kind of weird to me, and I didn't find a targeted answer. It might be some peculiarity of Java.A cloud disk project is used to learn Java, using Google's Gson library.

```
public class FileInit {
    String path;

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    //Query file method, will return a list containing file information
    public String queryFiles() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        //Query the path and build a File collection
        File file = new File(path);
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        //Build a List to store the converted FileItem
        List<FileItem> fileItems = new ArrayList<>();
        //Traversing files to make judgments
        for (File f:files){
            FileItem fileItem = new FileItem(f);
            fileItem.printFile();
            fileItems.add(fileItem);
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(fileItems);
    }
    //formatted output
    public void printFiles(String files){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<FileItem>>(){}.getType();
        List<FileItem> fileItems = gson.fromJson(files, type);
        // Format output file list
        int count = 0;
        for (FileItem f :fileItems ) {
            String name;
            if (f.getFileType()==null){
                name = f.getFileName() + "/";
            }else {
                name = f.getFileName();
            }
            System.out.printf("%-40s", name);
            count++;
            if (count % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    //Change directory command
    public void changeDic(String addPath){
        File fileDic1 = new File(path+addPath);
        File fileDic2 = new File(addPath);
        if (addPath.equals("..")) {
            File parent = new File(path).getParentFile();
            if (parent != null) {
                this.path = parent.getPath();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Parent directory does not exist");
            }
        }
        else {
            if (fileDic1.exists()){
                this.path = path+addPath;
            } else if (fileDic2.exists()) {
                this.path = addPath;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Illegal input path");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class FileItem {
    private String fileName;
    private String fileHash;
    private String filePath;
    private long fileLength;
    private String fileType;

    //Construction method of FileItem
    /*
Build a construction method that only needs fileName and filePath, and judge whether to calculate the hash value, file size, and file type according to the folder or file
*/
    public FileItem(String fileName,String filePath) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        File file =new File(this.filePath+"/"+this.fileName);
        if (file.isFile()){
            try {
                //Get the file size through the file built-in method
                this.fileLength = file.length();
                // Define a regular expression for extracting the suffix of the file name
                String regex = "\\.(\\w+)$";
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);
                // If the match is successful
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    // Get the suffix of the file name
                    this.fileType = matcher.group(1);
                }else{
                    this.fileType = null;
                }
                //Calculate the Hash value of the file by calling the FileHash method
                this.fileHash=FileHash(file.getPath());
                System.out.printf(fileHash);
                System.out.print("\n");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }else{
            this.fileName=fileName;
            this.fileLength=0;
            this.fileType = null;
            this.fileHash=null;
        }
    }

    //Build a constructor that only needs a json file
    public FileItem(String json){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        FileItem fileItem = gson.fromJson(json,FileItem.class);
        this.fileName=fileItem.getFileName();
        this.filePath=fileItem.getFilePath();
        this.fileHash=fileItem.getFileHash();
        this.fileLength=fileItem.getFileLength();
        this.fileType=fileItem.getFileType();
    }

    //Realize mutual conversion between FileItem and File class
    public File toFile(){
        return new File(this.filePath+"/"+this.fileName);
    }

    public FileItem(File file) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        FileItem fileItem = new FileItem(file.getName(),file.getPath());
        this.fileName=fileItem.getFileName();
        this.filePath=fileItem.getFilePath();
        this.fileHash=fileItem.getFileHash();
        this.fileLength=fileItem.getFileLength();
        this.fileType=fileItem.getFileType();
    }

    //Display FileItem related information
    public void printFile(){
        if (fileType==null){
            System.out.println(fileName+"是文件夹");
        }else {
            System.out.println(fileName+"是"+fileType+"文件");
        }
        double fileLenOp=(double)fileLength;
        //Different file sizes use different output methods
        if(fileLength<=1024*1024){
            System.out.printf("file size is:%.3fKB\n",fileLenOp/1024);
        } else if ((fileLength<1024*1024*1024)) {
            System.out.printf("file size is:%.3fMB\n",fileLenOp/1024/1024);
        }else {
            System.out.printf("file size is:%.3fGB\n",fileLenOp/1024/1024/1024);
        }
        System.out.println("file hash is:"+fileHash);
    }


    //Getter and Setter methods for FileItem

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileHash() {
        return fileHash;
    }

    public void setFileHash(String fileHash) {
        this.fileHash = fileHash;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public long getFileLength() {
        return fileLength;
    }

    public void setFileLength(long fileLength) {
        this.fileLength = fileLength;
    }

    public String getFileType() {
        return fileType;
    }

    public void setFileType(String fileType) {
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }
}
```

I try to query the file information in a folder by using the methods related to the File class. And return them as a collection. Then realize the conversion of the File class and the FileItem class by traversing this collection to form a new FileItem class collection , so that it can be converted into Json format data for network transmission. However, all fileitems in the generated FileItem collection are judged as folders. And if you comment out the FileItem related content, the judgment of File will be normal, but if you don’t do this , the judgment of File will always remain false.

Comment: I haven't spent too much time looking at your code, but in the `FileItem(File)` constructor `FileItem fileItem = new FileItem(file.getName(),file.getPath());` should be `this(file.getName(),file.getPath());`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).